# What bootstrap library need to use modal-body?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have following HTML, but it does not render bootstrap modal dialog. Do I need maybe an other version of Bootstrap?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="modal-body">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <i class="fas fa-check fa-4x mb-3 animated rotateIn"></i>
    <h5>#if(campaign.creatorID == "FE4E6920-A920-4AEB-8977-60BF51EC1CE7"){Merci de coller le texte après avoir continué.}else if(campaign.creatorID == "0B4DC579-EB0E-47E9-B5C2-F2EB3B1BFFC7"){Plak de tekst na het doorgaan.}else{#if(whitelabel.pleasePasteAfterContinuing){#(whitelabel.pleasePasteAfterContinuing)}else{Please paste the text after continuing.}}<br/></h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, but you need to use the JS files as well. Not just css would work all the functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only CSS files won't work properly. You have to add ***Javascript*** files as well to perform all the functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap 4.0 version modal-body is used inside of modal class.
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/modal/

And also you need to add js files.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the following link [Introduction - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/).

Before you even need to scroll down you will see the required Bootstrap Scripts as well as stylesheets.

Make sure to reference the stylesheets in your `<head></head>` before the scripts like so!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  
  <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  
  <body>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

See the [Modal - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/)

Comment: He appended styles for Material Design Bootstrap but you're right. He need to add js files.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, and then our JavaScript plugins.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I hope this will be help you out